# Why is WillPopScope deprecated?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Old Code**

```
WillPopScope(
   onWillPop: () async{
      //
     })
```

**New Code**

```
PopScope(
  canPop: true,
  onPopInvoked : (didPop){
   // logic
  },
)
```

Comment: The deprecation is due to the new Android predictive back, see [this answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138614#issuecomment-1819505507), or the full document on that topic [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BGCWy1_LRrXEB6qeqTAKlk-U2CZlKJ5xI97g45U7azk/edit)